# if 文を列挙する記述から、if else を使った記述に変更したい

Tags: python

最近Pythonを勉強し始めましたが、課題で行き詰まっています。
どなたかアドバイスください。

課題の指示は以下の通り。

- Between 37 and 38 degrees Celsiusの時　Normal Body temperatureと表示させる
- Between 38 and 39 degrees Celsiusの時　Is a Feverと表示させる
- Between 39 and 40 degrees Celsiusの時　Is a High Feverと表示させる
- Between 40 and 41 degrees Celsiusの時　Is A Very High Feverと表示させる
- Over 41 degrees Celsiusの時　Is A Serious Emergencyと表示させる

コードは以下の通り作成しました。ひとまず指示通りの結果は表示させることはできたのですが、if elseを使う場合はどのように記述したら良いでしょうか？

```
print("What is your body tempereture? ", end="")
n=float(input())

if n>= 37.0 and n<=38.0:
    print("Nomal Body Tempereture")
    
if n>=38.1 and n<=39.0:
    print("Is a Fever")
    
if n>=39.1 and n<=40.0:
    print("Is a High Fever")

if n>=40.1 and n<=41.0:
    print("Is A Very High Fever")
    
if n>=41.1:
    print("Is A Serious Emergency")
```

Comment: コードは画像でなく文字で記述してください。

Comment: コードはリンクではなくテキスト（マークダウン）でここに記入してください。（参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting）また、「if else」の使い方については習っていますか？

Comment: Pythonの仕様説明の記事 [4.1. if 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements), [8.1. if 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) や誰かが書いた解説記事 [if 文](https://murashun.jp/article/programming/python/python_how_to_write_conditional_branches.html#chapter-1) 等を探して読み解いてみましょう。質問内容は比較的簡単なので、いくつかの事例を見れば推測出来るでしょう。

Comment: sayuriさん　回答ありがとうございます。今後コードは文字で記述します。ありがとうございました。

Comment: merinoさん　回答ありがとうございます。　if elseの使い方は習いました。ただ、英語で学習しているのではっきりと把握できず、日本語で質問させていただきました。

Comment: kunifさん　回答ありがとうございます。いくつか事例になる問題をネット検索したのですが、はっきり把握できずにいます。もう少し勉強してみます。

Comment: 「今後コードは文字で記述します。」と言っていますが、質問は編集できますので「今後」ではなく「今」この質問を編集して文字にで記述してください。なおそうとしないのであれば、質の悪い質問と評価されることになります。

Comment: raccyさん　アドバイスどうもありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 公式マニュアルのチュートリアルを読むと良さそうです: https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

`if` は「この条件に合ったら○○する」という制御構文であり、同じような感じで `else` は「それ以外の場合は○○する」、`elif` は「それ以外の場合で、この条件に合ったら○○する」という制御構文です。

このためたとえば以下のように書くことができます。

```
if n >= 37.0 and n <= 38.0:
    print("Normal Body Temperature")
elif n <= 39.0:
    print("Is a Fever")
elif n <= 40.0:
    print("Is a High Fever")
else:
    # 以下省略します。
    print("Something else")
```

この書き方の良いところは、少し条件を省略できるところです。つまり、ひとつ前の条件で既にチェックされていることはチェックしなくて良くなります。このため、実は今回の場合結果的にバグめいた挙動がひとつ直っており、「38.01」みたいな入力があっても何かしら出力されるようになっています。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん　回答ありがとうございます。分かりやすい解説です！とても助かりました。公式サイトも後ほど確認して、もっと理解を深めたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決したようで良かったです。
ぜひ[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん　回答の承認しました。ありがとうございました！